# C++ - Error Creating a Pyramid with a Recursive Function

Tags: c++, function, recursion

So I've been trying to figure out why this is not working. Basically I attempted to write a recursive function that will display a nice text pyramid in the console.

Users enter the height first, and then the symbol used to create the pyramid, and the function is called here:

```
//_pyramidHeight is 10
//The second int is to specify the beginning width, which should be the point at the top.    
pyramidLine(_pyramidHeight, 1);
```

The function I created is here:

```
void pyramidLine (int _height, int _width)
{
    for (; _height > 0; _height--, _width + 2)
    {
        cout << setfill (' ') << setw(_height - 1);
        cout << setfill (_pyramidBase) << setw(_width);

        pyramidLine (_height, _width);
    }

    return;
}
```

The error given is this: Unhandled exception at 0x00c823e9 in Kevin_CIS121.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow
As soon as it gets to the first cout of the for loop.

I'm really not sure at this point...

Answer (score 2):

Simple: you never hit a base case. You have infinite recursion because `_height--` is evaluated *after* each iteration of your `for` loop, not before. Consider `pyramidLine (_height-1, _width);`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do recursively, you can do iteratively too. Iterating won't cause a stack overflow like recursion may. Try to re-write it using iteration.

Comment: I forgot to mention but my professor said that it the function used in pyramid creation must be recursive.